# SSRS report renders differently in Report Viewer from Report Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rendering

In my report I have two row groups, one header row and one details row. I want the header row to stay fixed at the top of the page and not be visible while scrolling. I obviously want to the details row to behave the same, so I've set both row groups' FixedData property to True.

When I preview the report in Report Viewer in Visual Studio 2013, it renders as intended. However, when I run the same report deployed to a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Report Server, this is the resulting rendering:

[image]

Once I scroll down past the header row, it displays at the top as I'm scrolling, and the details rows seem to pile up on each other, as each row you scroll past stays visible.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: If you export the data to Excel, does it overlap like the screenshot?

Comment: @WEI_DBA No, it looks fine in Excel.

Comment: If you open the report from Report Builder in the portal and view it, does it produce the same results? I'm thinking it may need to be upgraded to SSRS 2014.

Comment: What browser/version are you using?

Comment: @PaulBambury I do not have Report Builder installed. It happens across all browsers.

Comment: Bit confused about what you mean by "I've set both row groups' FixedData..."? You want the header row to be fixed while scrolling. So you only need to set the FixedData property on the outermost (usually the top static group in the row groupspane).